# Mongoose Schema with Typescript - Design errors

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have two problems defining schema using mongoose and typescript.
Here is my code:

```
import { Document, Schema, Model, model} from "mongoose";

export interface IApplication {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    virtualProperty: string;
}

interface IApplicationModel extends Document, IApplication {} //Problem 1

let ApplicationSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    id: { type: Number, required: true, index: true, unique: true},
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
});
ApplicationSchema.virtual('virtualProperty').get(function () {
    return `${this.id}-${this.name}/`; // Problem 2
});
export const IApplication: Model<IApplicationModel> = model<IApplicationModel>("Application", ApplicationSchema);
```

First of all:

- Problem 1 in this line

`interface IApplicationModel extends Document, IApplication {}`

The Typescript is telling me that:

`error TS2320: Interface 'IApplicationModel' cannot simultaneously extend types 'Document' and 'IApplication'.
  Named property 'id' of types 'Document' and 'IApplication' are not identical.`

So how to change definition of `id` property?

- Problem 2 is in inner function (getter for `virtualProperty`):

  return `${this.id}-${this.name}/; // Problem 2

The Error is:

`error TS2683: 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.`

How to define type of `this`?

Answer (score 0):

Problem #1: Since `IApplicationModel` extends interfaces `Document` and `IApplication` that declare the `id` property with different types (`any` and `number` respectively), TypeScript does not know whether the `id` property of `IApplicationModel` should be of type `any` or `number`.  You can fix this by redeclaring the `id` property in `IApplicationModel` with the desired type.  (Why are you declaring a separate `IApplication` interface rather than just declaring `IApplicationModel` that extends `Document` with all your properties?)

Problem #2: Just declare the `this` special parameter to the function as shown below.

```
import { Document, Schema, Model, model} from "mongoose";

export interface IApplication {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    virtualProperty: string;
}

interface IApplicationModel extends Document, IApplication {
    id: number;
}

let ApplicationSchema: Schema = new Schema({
    id: { type: Number, required: true, index: true, unique: true},
    name: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
});
ApplicationSchema.virtual('virtualProperty').get(function (this: IApplicationModel) {
    return `${this.id}-${this.name}/`;
});
export const IApplication: Model<IApplicationModel> = model<IApplicationModel>("Application", ApplicationSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

for problem 2: just declare `this` as `any` : `.get(function (this: any) {});` fix it

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.